# How to jump to the next page in a PrintDocument?

Tags: c#, winforms, printdocument

I have an application that prints how many bar codes you want, but if the amount of bar codes is bigger than the size of the [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) it doesn't jump to the next page.

I'd like to know how can I add more pages or write in the next page of a [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx).

[image: printscreen]

I'm using a PrintPreview to display the PrintDocument in this Windows Form.

Comment: Use the [e.HasMorePages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.hasmorepages.aspx) property in your PrintPage event handler.  Covered well in this [how-to MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwbe712d.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you hookup the OnPrintPage event you can tell the PrintDocument if it needs to add another page on the PrintPageEventArguments.

```
IEnumerator items;

public void StartPrint()
{
   PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
   pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);
   items = GetEnumerator();
   if (items.MoveNext())
   {
       pd.Print();
   }
}

private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    const int neededHeight = 200;
    int line =0;
    // this will be called multiple times, so keep track where you are...
    // do your drawings, calculating how much space you have left on one page
    bool more = true;
    do
    {
        // draw your bars for item, handle multilple columns if needed
        var item = items.Current;
        line++;
        // in the ev.MarginBouds the width and height of this page is available
        // you use that to see if a next row will fit
        if ((line * neededHeight) < ev.MarginBounds.Height )
        {
            break;
        }
        more = items.MoveNext();
    } while (more);
    // stop if there are no more items in your Iterator
    ev.HasMorePages = more;
}
```